# Uploading a base64 image from react-webcam to cloudinary via Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cloudinary

I'm new to react and any help is appreciated. 
I have the following code that works when it comes to uploading a jpg with  to cloudinary via Node.

onChange in  calls the following method;

```
uploadProfilePic = e => {
  const files = Array.from(this.state.profilePic)
  const formData = new FormData()

  files.forEach((file, i) => {
    formData.append(i, file)
  })
    fetch(`http://localhost:3030/imageUpload`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(images => {
      this.setState({profilePic: images[0].url})
    })
  }
```

and in my server.js file;

```
  const values = Object.values(req.files)
    const promises = values.map(image => cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.path))

    Promise
      .all(promises)
      .then(results => res.json(results))
  })
```

above successfully uploads the jpg to cloudinary and sets the url to my state as intended.

Just wondering how to tweak the 2 code blocks above to be able to upload a **base64 image*** that was captured via react-webcam which is stored in my state `{this.state.passImage}` to achieve the same result(aka upload to cloudinary and retrieve the URL)?

so far I've tried

```
uploadPassImage= e => {

const formData = JSON.stringify(this.state.passImage)

    fetch(`http://localhost:3030/imageUploadPassImage`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(images => {
      this.setState({passImage: images[0].url})
    })
  }
```

with the server code;

```
  app.post('/imageUploadPassImage', (req, res) => {
    const values = Object.values(req.files)
      const promises = values.map(image => cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.path))

      Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(results => res.json(results))
    })
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone wondering or encountering the same issue, I'll post it here.

on react

```
uploadPassImage= e => {
const files = Array.of(this.state.passImage)


    const formData = new FormData()

    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      formData.append(i, file)
    })
      fetch(`http://localhost:3030/imageUploadPassImage`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(images => {
        this.setState({passImage: images[0].url}) 
//sets the data in the state for uploading into SQL database later
      })
    }
```

on the server;

```
app.post('/imageUploadPassImage', (req, res) => {
   const values = Object.values(req.body)
      const promises = values.map(image => cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(image,
  function(error, result) {console.log(result, error); }));

      Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(results => res.json(results))
    })
```